# Any video editing software with own codecs?

Tags: video-editor, codec

I just tried the new Lightworks and even though I followed the installation instructions rigorously I managed to hit codec problems.

Is there any (preferably proprietary) video editing software with own codecs so that it would run on any Windows? I just want the software to work. Preferably without crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed Sony Vegas Movie Studio HD ($34). The download took half a minute, the same to install it, no prerequisities ( except the software updated windows installer ) and everything worked and has been working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what your end goal is, Sony Vegas is nice but VERY outdated, youd be better off spending the extra money on Premiere